# Are implementations allowed to add public members to standard types?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

Are C++ standard library implementations allowed to add public (and protected) members to standard types' interfaces? N3797 17.6.5.5 [member.functions]/2 says:

> An implementation may declare additional non-virtual member function signatures within a class:
>
> — by adding arguments with default values to a member function signature; [ *Note*: An implementation may not add arguments with default values to virtual, global, or non-member functions. — *end note* ]
>
> — by replacing a member function signature with default values by two or more member function signatures with equivalent behavior; and
>
> — by adding a member function signature for a member function name.

Does this mean that a standard library cannot add any additional public members with names not mentioned in the standard under any circumstances (that include, for example, reserved identifiers)?

A tiny bit of explanation: this is the text about adding signatures (which I assume talks about new signatures just for functions that are already defined to be there, so no new *names*) I managed to find in the standard. There is also the footnote 189, which says:

> A valid C++ program always calls the expected library member function, or one with equivalent behavior. An implementation may also define additional member functions that would otherwise not be called by a valid C++ program.

All this text originates from [member.functions], so it is clearly about member functions only. My question is more generic and asks for any references I could've missed: is a standard library implementation allowed to add new *names* to public (and/or protected) interfaces of a standard type, be it data or function members?

Comment: It looks like footnote 189 says it's ok ... I have to parse the section again to make sure though. It says: `A valid C++ program always calls the expected library member function, or one with equivalent behavior. An implementation
may also define additional member functions that would otherwise not be called by a valid C++ program.`

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, hmm, possible. The wording is at least a bit confusing, though. I understand this is a formal text, but formal texts should also be written in a manner that can be understood without staring at it for ten minutes.

Comment: Hmm, I guess the difference between "signature" and "function" is kind of crucial here, but it is probably buried in the text somewhere.

Comment: Are you asking about public *data* members? I'm a little confused because the paragraph you quoted says it can add members and then you ask if that means it can't.

Comment: Only point I'm unsure about is the last one. The others are pretty straightforward: "Don't break any code written against the standard conformant implementation." But the last one, as it's quoted above, would only suggest adding a new signature (with different parameters), rather than a new name as well?

Comment: @JosephMansfield, I am asking about public members. What I quoted in the question is the text I could find, and it speaks about "non-virtual member function signatures", but the question is more general than function or data members. I should probably say "names" somewhere in the question.

Comment: It seems like `17.6.5.11` *Derived classes* probably covers what you are looking for it says `An implementation may derive any class in the C++ standard library from a class with a name reserved to
the implementation.` and it does not provide any restrictions on those base classes. `gcc` uses this all over the place although most public data members are made protected in the stl class using something like `using _Base::_M_impl;` in the protected section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you have what you need with a combination of foot note `189` which says:

> A valid C++ program always calls the expected library member function, or one with equivalent behavior. An implementation may also define additional member functions that would otherwise not be called by a valid C++ program.

and section `17.6.5.11` *Derived classes* which says:

> An implementation may derive any class in the C++ standard library from a class with a name reserved to the implementation.

but does not add any restrictions, i.e. it does not let's say restrict the access qualifiers etc...

and we can see [libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/) uses derived classes pretty effectively, for example in [stl_vector.h](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a01069_source.html). Although as far as I can see `libstdc++` does seem to eschew adding public data members but that is probably more for clean design.

At minimum, this looks under-specified but if you stick to something similar to `libstdc++` implementation style you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the key to reading footnote 189 is the phrase `would otherwise not be called by a valid C++ program`.

Remember that identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter (or containing two consecutive underscores anywhere) are reserved for the implementation. (section 17.6.4.3.2)

So implementations are free to add public/protected member functions that are named in that manner.

For example, in libc++, `std::vector` has a protected member function named `__throw_length_error`