# Does std::initializer_list private constructor get very special treatment from compiler?

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

The GCC's libstdc++'s [source code for `std::initializer_list`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/libstdc++/api/a01335_source.html) has the following part:

```
private:
  iterator                  _M_array;
  size_type                 _M_len;

  // The compiler can call a private constructor.
  constexpr initializer_list(const_iterator __a, size_type __l)
  : _M_array(__a), _M_len(__l) { }
```

How does this happen to work? Is calling a private constructor for `std::initializer_list` a special exception hard-coded into compiler code? Or does GCC have some internal functionality that can be potentially used to expose any private member of any class?

(I've seem the [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200036/is-providing-a-private-constructor-for-initializer-list-conforming), but it only mentions that

> However, initializer_list is a type that depends on some magic
>   being done by the compiler. By magic, I'm referring to §8.5.4/5 that
>   you've quoted.

which does not actually explain how the compiler does it. My question is not about whether I can call that constructor in my code, or what in the standard allows for it, but how internally gcc manages to see that a private constructor in this case can be called.)

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of that? Later on in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29200426/1896169) you quoted, it reads, "Here, as explained in §8.5.4/5, the compiler will create an array containing the four integers, and then initialize the initializer_list<int> instance with either a pair of pointers (first element and one past the end element) or a pointer and length (which is what both libstdc++ and libc++ seem to do)." That explains how it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is providing a private constructor for initializer\_list conforming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200036/is-providing-a-private-constructor-for-initializer-list-conforming)

Comment: @Justin, it does not explain what happens internally in gcc. The question is not about whether I can call that constructor in my code, but how internally gcc manages to see that a private constructor in this case can be called.

Comment: "As the comment above the libstdc++ private constructor definition implies, the compiler is capable of emitting code that bypasses normal access control"

Comment: @Justin, but how the compiler understands that in this case it is allowed to bypass? Is, for example, `initializer_list` hard-coded somewhere in the compiler source code?

Comment: Yes. `initializer_list` requires special treatment. Exactly how the different compilers handles that special treatment is up to them

Comment: @Justin, and this is my question -- how gcc internally handles this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC's C++ frontend doesn't actually use that private constructor. [It uses no constructor at all](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/ca16a224db6365db0dbcbda5e2269931b1505d1b/gcc/cp/call.c#L6860-L6866):

```
/* Build up the initializer_list object.  */
totype = complete_type (totype);
field = next_initializable_field (TYPE_FIELDS (totype));
CONSTRUCTOR_APPEND_ELT (vec, field, array);
field = next_initializable_field (DECL_CHAIN (field));
CONSTRUCTOR_APPEND_ELT (vec, field, size_int (len));
new_ctor = build_constructor (totype, vec);
```

This essentially emits code that simply store the pointer into the first field of the `initializer_list` object and the size into the second field.